How did owner remove token liquidity during trading on DEX even if their ownership is renounced?
Im non-tech trader. Today I experienced that the owner did remove token liquidity during trading on DEX and made it become honypot even if their ownership is renounced (checked via Token Sniffer)
I don't understand how this is possible since the token ownership was renounced, so I assumed no one could remove liquidity and turned it to a honeypot.
I really need someone to educate me on why this can happen and how to avoid contracts where liquidity can be removed even if ownership is renounced.
Token address: https://etherscan.io/token/0x1dd4313ded26220c08b0d58567af3d7f98643f93
DEX: https://dexscreener.com/ethereum/0xb7a590fe5d91a542aa7c0e94c34df2a6ea51828f
Thank you so much!
Regards.

Liquidity was removed on Uniswap contract, there is no need to be owner or to control the token to remove liquidity from Uniswap. Here the tx.
